# How do I send a photo with Mail.app to a Windows user so that they can download it?

Tags: windows, macos, email

I have sent a photo to a friend using Apple Mail, but although she can see it, she can’t “save as”.  How can I send it as an attachment?

Comment: How did you send the photo? Did you drag/drop it into the mail body? Have you added it as an attachment? How can your friend not "Save as"? How is it displayed?

Comment: I drag/dropped it. I can’t see how to add it as an attachment.

Comment: The problem will probably rather be on your friend's side. Please be more specific: What did you do exactly to get the image into the mail? What software is your friend using to display the mail? What happens when they right-click the image, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.  I have done it the same way and sent to others with no problem.  I thought it must be me so sorted now. Thanks for your help